# Selenium Side Runner - preview of test / steps

Tags: selenium, ide, runner, selenium-side-runner

I'm just getting started with automated tests, I've started using Selenium IDE. I run the tests via the **Selenium Side Runner**, the tests execute correctly, I can see if the test passes or fails, however a browser window opens but I can't see the steps preview (step by step). It just executes quickly and sort of in the background, after which I can only see the test result in the CMD.

How can I solve this problem so that I can see the process of testing in the browser?